# How to write short codes in brackets?

Tags: emmet, adobe-brackets

Just like in sublime you can type `foo.bar`, press `Tab`, and you'll get `<foo class="bar"></foo>`. There's also foo#bar (for id instead of class).

How can we do this in Brackets editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is called [Emmet](http://emmet.io/).

1. Run Brackets.
2. Select File > Extension Manager...
3. Find “Emmet” extension and click “Install” button

([source](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet#readme))

[Here is the list](http://emmet.io/download/) of all supported platforms.